# SQLAlchemy "or" statement with multiple parameters

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a query that require to use the "or" `|` operator :

```
Mymodel.query.filter((Mymodel.a== 'b') | (Mymodel.b == 'c'))
```

That works fine. However, I want my conditions to be put in an array of unkown length :

```
conds = [ Mymodel.a== 'b', Mymodel.b == 'c', Mymodel.c == 'd']
Mymodel.query.filter(???(conds))
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are looking for [or_](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.or_)

```
conds = [ Mymodel.a== 'b', Mymodel.b == 'c', Mymodel.c == 'd']
```

If you have the above list of conditions just pass them all to or_

```
from sqlalchemy import or_
Mymodel.query.filter(or_(*conds))
```