# How to filter a query by list of columns in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

in my case i have a list of names representing columns in the table i am querying about.
How can i filter the query so that i can check every column if the field is not 0?

In SQL it would look something like `...WHERE Column_1 != 0 or Column_2 != 0 or Column_3 != 0...`

```
header_texts = ["Column_1", "Column_2", ... "Column_n"]    
query = query.filter(or_(header_texts != 0))
```

The code above obviously does not work but to give you an idea what i want to achieve. What i basically dont know is where to put the "!= 0" comparison.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLAlchemy "or" statement with multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30123365/sqlalchemy-or-statement-with-multiple-parameters)

Comment: Yes, so i can put terms in a list and put that in or_(). So how can i do something like:
term = ("Column_1" != 0) without interpreting it?